# How to use MediaPipe in C#?

Tags: c#, tensorflow-lite, mediapipe

I would like to use the [Face Mesh application](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/face_mesh.html) from Media Pipe in a C# project. As the library is not impemented in C#, I looked for solutions. I found that my face mesh model is saved in [tflite](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/modules/face_landmark/face_landmark.tflite) but I don't know how to use it.

Is there a simple way to use a tflite model in C#? Or maybe a way to use directly MediaPipe in C#?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to directly use MediaPipe in a C# project.

You have 2 options:

- Figure out what the MediaPipe pipeline is doing, do those operations yourself and run the tflite model(s) directly using something like [emgutf](https://github.com/emgucv/emgutf)
- Wait for (or contribute towards) [Vignette's wrapper](https://github.com/vignetteapp/MediaPipe.NET)